# Navigating to the wrong slug - but no error? Path issue?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, path, slug, sanity

I have two slugs. I want to access the second one [product] but it keeps directing me to the first one instead [slug]. I have them in separate folders, I'm not getting any error messages. It just keeps redirecting to the first slug and not the second slug for some reason. Using Sanity as my backend and Nextjs as my frontend.

I'm trying to do this from my `shop.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { client, urlFor } from '../lib/client';
import { Header, Footer } from '../components';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Shop = ({getProduct}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <main className="main-shop">
            <div className="title">
                <div className="title-line-left"></div>
                <h2>for sale</h2>
                <div className="title-line-right"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="shop">
              <ul className="products">
                {getProduct && getProduct.map((getProduct, index) => (
                  <Link href={`/${getProduct.slug.current}`}>
                    <li key={index}>
                      <a href="./products/[product].js"><img src={urlFor(getProduct.productImage).auto('format').url()} alt={getProduct.productName}/></a>
                      <span className="product-name">{getProduct.productName}</span>
                      <span className="product-price">${getProduct.price}.00</span>
                    </li>
                  </Link>
                ))}
              </ul>
          </div>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Shop

export const getServerSideProps = async (pageContext) => {
  const productQuery = `*[_type == 'products']{productName, slug, price, productImage}`;
  const getProduct = await client.fetch(productQuery);

  return {
    props: {getProduct}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: your products live on `/products/{your-product-id}`. If you navigate to `/{your-product-id}` you'll end up on your `[slug].js` route.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this, and finding it pretty confusing. Could you elaborate please? I don't want it to navigate to my [slug], because I have different styles and fetched data between the slug (which I'm using for my gallery images) and my product (for products)

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL that is causing your issue? Then I can probably show you what is wrong and fix it.

Comment: Sure. I have a shop page, one of the products is called 'Not Rot'. It goes from localhost:3000/shop, then I click the link, it changes to localhost:3000/product-not-rot. Same deal with my original slug, from localhost:3000/gallery to localhost:3000/not-rot. They both go to [slug], though I want the first to go to [product] instead.

Comment: I understand. Your link on one of the products should go to `/products/not-rot`. (notice the / and the folder structure)

Comment: The `products` directory inside of your `pages` directory works as any directory. Try adding a file named `test.js` inside the `products` folder. now you can access this file via `localhost:3000/products/test`.

Comment: Ah about that, I had tried having `<Link href={'/products/${getProduct.slug.current}'}>` instead, but got a separate issue so I wasn't sure if that was a good move or not. Thank you for clarifying! By any chance, do you know why I keep getting the 'Module not found' errors after doing that? I fixed my import like so: `import { client, urlFor } from '/next_portfolio/lib/client.js';` but it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Never mind, I think I've nearly got it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hard to say what the issue is. but I've posted a basic example to show the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hard to judge your issue because I dont know what your `getProduct` array looks like, but consider the following example as inspiration.

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const ProductOverview = () => {
  const products = [
    { name: "Not rot", slug: "not-rot", price: 10 },
    { name: "T-shirt", slug: "tshirt", price: 28 },
    { name: "Coffee mug", slug: "coffee-mug", price: 4 },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product, index) => (
        <Link href={`/products/${product.slug}`} key={index]>
          <h4>{product.name}</h4>
          <p>{product.price}</p>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductOverview;
```

this produces the following three links:

- `/products/not-rot`
- `/products/tshirt`
- `/products/coffee-mug`

Your file `[product].js` in `/products` catches anything that is posted to `/products/{anything}` and will display the that page. Getting the data and content linked to that page is another challenge tho.